# How to show notice alert only on product dashboard page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to remind to my plugin users that the plugin is enabled but only on `product` page (dashboard), i've came across the `$pagenow` global variable:

```
global $pagenow;
$pagenow != 'post.php'; // This will be shown on "normal posts" too
```

How can i add a notice alert only on product page? This is what i have at the moment:

```
add_action('admin_notices', function () {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    $title = __e('Your plugin is enabled');
    $div = '<div class="notice notice-info is-dismissible"><p>%s</p></div>';

    $pluginPath = 'path-to/my-plugin.php';
    if (is_plugin_active($pluginPath)) {
        echo sprintf($div, $title);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd guess there'll be a `post_type=product` query string parameter that you can test for too?

Comment: (I'd also guess that is_admin will always be true in an admin_init handler, but there's no harm in checking.)

Comment: @Rup on product editing page there's no `?post_type=product` query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on wp-admin/post.php, you've got either

- [`global $post_type`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.4.1/wp-admin/post.php#L30)
- or possibly `$_POST['post_type']`, if we don't have a post ID to look up the type from

that you can test for 'product'. See the first 50 lines of wp-admin/post.php.

As an aside, I don't think you need to check for is_admin in a admin_init handler; nor do you need to check if your plugin is enabled if this code is in the same plugin, since it won't be run unless the plugin is enabled. Unless you're testing for a different plugin that is.